# A function that takes a string and character and slices up to (including) the first occurrence of the character?

Tags: python

Sorry for the newbie question, stackoverflow was a last resort but I really can't figure this out.

I'm doing a homework problem and it asks the following:
1. Write a function that takes a string, s, and a single character, ch, and returns a slice of s up to and including the first occurrence of ch. If the character is not present it should return an empty string. The function should pass the following doctests:

I was going to try make a variable within the definition and make it contain whatever the argument ch is and try slice up to it but couldn't figure out how or if there was a more viable option.

````
    """
    >>> find_slice("abcdefghijk", "f")
    'abcdef'
    >>> find_slice("aaabbbccc", "b")
    'aaab'
    >>> find_slice("aaabbbccc", "d")
    ''
    """
    for letters in s:
        if ch in s:

    return emptystring

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod(verbose=True)```
````

Comment: You did _nothing_ to solve your task at hand. look into string slicing and `str.ìndex(character)` to get the position of the first occurence

Comment: The process of learing how to code is 90% the process to learn problem solving. Start googeling and _try_ to solve it - read [open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems). If you do not solve beginner tasks you wont be able to follow more complex tasks that build upon what you should have aquired as skills solving the smaller ones.

Comment: As other has pointed out, you show no effort in trying to solve the solution. You want to *slice* a *string* in *python*, so start by googleing *Python string slice* and read! If you run into issues when finding the *first occurence* of a *character* in the *string*, Google *Python first occurence character string* and read some more! Then, if you still have not figured it out you should start asking a question and be specific on what exactly you can not figure out. I even Googled the exact title of your question and came up with a result on the first page with all the information needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Little better version of @Austin's answer, using `.find`, works even when the string does not contain that character:

```
def find_slice(s, chr):
    return s[:s.find(chr)+1]
```

Answer (score 3):

Use string `index()` which is guaranteed to return first index of the character in string and use that in a slice:

```
def find_slice(s, c):
    return s[:s.index(c)+1]
```

An optional `try`-`except` to handle `ValueError`:

```
def find_slice(s, c):
    try:
        return s[:s.index(c)+1]
    except ValueError:
        return ''
```